# matrix bernstein's inequality: from tail probability to expectation

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, measure-concentration

Let $X_i$ be independent, mean zero, $n\times n$, symmetric random matrices. $\|X_i\|\leq K$ almost sure for $\forall I$.

We have matrix Bernstein's inequality for the tail probability as follows

$$\forall t\geq 0,P(\|\sum X_i\|\geq t)\leq 2n \cdot\text{exp}(-\frac{t^2}{\sigma^2+Kt/3})$$
where $\sigma^2=\|\sum \mathbb{E}X_i^2\|$.

My question is how to prove
$$\|\sum X_i\|\lesssim\|\sum \mathbb{E}X_i^2\|^{1/2}\sqrt{1+\log n}+K(1+\log n)$$?

Comment: for bounding the expectation you can use the layercake principle $E[Z]=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(Z>t)dt$ for nonnegative Z.

Comment: for getting an almost sure statement $|\sum X_i|\lessapprox t_{n}$, you could try a Borel-Cantelli argument for $A_{n}:=|\sum X_i|>t_{n}$ and then use the concentration inequality you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Exercise 5.4.11 in Vershynin's book [High-Dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf). The book gives strong hints on how to solve it. It has also been discussed on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3759461/an-elementary-application-of-integral-identity). Hope you can figure it out from here.